# Instantly hate or hated you

Tags: grammar, tense

Let's say you're making a statement about some haters in your life. And you say:(making a statement that is still happening now)

> When you have achieved success simply because you **made** a stand and be yourself, some people would hate you due to envy, perhaps. Haters who instantly **hate/hated** you as they felt bad about themselves that they cannot reach your level now.

Do I have to say **hated** you?(I think this is the correct tense) but it still happening, or should I use just **hate**?

Comment: Since the situation being described "is still happening", it's more natural to use Present Tense ***hate***. But then you'd also need to match that with ***feel***, not ***felt***. I think you *could* reasonably use ***hated + felt***, which is consistent with the past tense of the preceding sentence, but in that case I'd also "backshift" ***cannot reach*** to ***could not reach***.

Comment: You have not written a valid sentence there (**Haters who ... your level now**). It lacks a main clause with finite verb. You could fix it by saying **They are haters who ...** and replacing **that** with **because**, or by appending it to the first sentence with some punctuation between, such as dash or a comma: **...envy perhaps—haters who ... because ...**

Comment: How about this: When you have achieved success simply because you had **made** a stand and be yourself, some people would hate you due to envy, perhaps; They are haters who instantly **hated** you as they felt bad about themselves *because* they **could not** reach your level now. Thx, OK now?

Comment: **had made** is past perfect: there is no event to place it before, so past perfect is wrong. simple past **made** is fine. **be yourself** is a to-less infinitive or an imperative, and neither works in this context. **by being yourself** would work.

Comment: @JavaLatte, Nice, so after that all is well now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, you're having problems with making your verbs agree on their tense.

"When you have achieved success … some people would" should be "some people will" for tense agreement.

"made and a stand and be" should be "made a stand and were" for tense agreement. And finally, this gets to your question, you should match the tense between hate/feel or hated/felt. Since made/were is past, I would lean towards hated/felt.

Comment: I have deleted 2 previous comments in this section, you are actually correct.

Answer (score 1):

I propose "*hated on you*" and here's why:

The term *haters* is informal and is usually used to describe any and all detractors of online "celebrities". It can be used to describe detractors offline but I wouldn't say it was as common.

The act of receiving online *hate* is characterised by rude/abusive comments on social media directed solely at an individual. It is often unfairly harsh, willfully ignorant and is often done to garner support from other *haters* in the form of likes or retweets.

When an individual receives mass online hate, I would argue they are not *hated* in a personal sense, but *hated on* in an anonymous, impersonal way.

I am very aware that this is poor English, but it is online slang to begin with.

If you feel that this is not relevant to you because the "haters in your life" are not online, but real people you have met, then it can still be used even though the magnitude is wrong. I'd say that rivals is a more personal term.

Comment: ''Online bashers'' may be the best term in your context, but not in my question. Thx anyway, I have just learned some new collocations-unfairly harsh, willfully ignorant hehe.